# is any way to determine that pivot selected index is changing wp7 to some particular index

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi I am setting pivot selected index to some value, do we have any event which will tell that pivot is done with index changing, not the selected index changed event as some times i am trying to get the index value while it is moving and that time i  m not getting the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the "selected index changed" or "SelectionChanged" event ??

**SelectionChanged** event occurs on the change of the selected item of the pivot control.

Every time, in handler of this event you get the **SelectedIndex** properly from the pivot class.

So add the event handler for the **SelectionChanged** event of pivot control and try.
It may help you.

[For more information on the Pivot class check this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)